# How do I delete all "children" of an object in my bucket?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Assume the following files exist in my bucket on S3

```
mybucket/folder1/folder2/myfile.txt
mybucket/folder1/folder2/myfile2.txt
mybucket/folder1/folder4/myfile3.txt
```

What I would like to do is delete all files that live under `mybucket/folder1/folder2/` without actually knowing exactly what files are there. I understand that the folders aren't real and are actually object keys, but I still need to achieve this effect.

I've tried deleting `mybucket/folder1/folder2/` (with and without the trailing slash) but it doesn't seem that anything is happening; nothing gets deleted. There are no errors and the HttpResponse is 204.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been awhile I don't touch the AmazonS3 service, but this is what you should do:

1. [list all object keys](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingNetSDK.html) in the path you want
2. <del>for each key, [issue a delete action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingOneObjectUsingNetSDK.html)</del> get all keys and [delete them in one go](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/01/working-with-s3-folders-using-the-net-aws-sdk/)

in code it should be something like (a rough compilation of the examples suggested):

```
static IAmazonS3 client;


static void DeleteFolderContents(string bucketName, string folderPath) 
{
    using (client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
    {
        var allKeys = GetFolderContents(bucketName, fodlerPath);       
        var allDeletes = DeleteAllKeys(bucketName, allKeys);

        // allDeletes has # of deleted objects
    }
}

// using DeleteObjectsRequest (all keys at once)
static int DeleteAllKeys(string bucketName, List<string> allKeys) 
{
    var multiObjectDeleteRequest = new DeleteObjectsRequest();
    multiObjectDeleteRequest.BucketName = bucketName;

    foreach(var key in allKeys)
        multiObjectDeleteRequest.AddKey(key, null); // version ID is null

    try
    {
        var response = client.DeleteObjects(multiObjectDeleteRequest);
        return response.DeletedObjects.Count;
    }
    catch (DeleteObjectsException e)
    {
        // throw exception.
    }

    return 0;
}

// delete one by one
static void DeleteKey(string bucketName, string keyName) 
{
    DeleteObjectRequest deleteObjectRequest = new DeleteObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = keyName
    };
    try
    {
        client.DeleteObject(deleteObjectRequest);
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception)
    {
        // throw
    }
}

// list all keys for a given path
static List<string> 
    GetFolderContents(string bucketName, string folderPath)
{
    var r = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Prefix = folderPath,
            MaxKeys = 100
        };

        do
        {
            ListObjectsResponse response = client.ListObjects(request);

            foreach (S3Object entry in response.S3Objects)
                r.Add(entry.Key);

            // If response is truncated, set the marker to get the next 
            // set of keys.
            if (response.IsTruncated)
                request.Marker = response.NextMarker;
            else
                request = null;
        } while (request != null);
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
    {
        // throw error
    }
}
```

You can also find a way to listen all keys in a folder by [looking at this article](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/01/working-with-s3-folders-using-the-net-aws-sdk/).

---

**edited**: added a one action call to delete all keys using [`DeleteObjectsRequest`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingMultipleObjectsUsingNetSDK.html) object.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. It's odd that I can list from "folders" but I can't delete the "folder"

Comment: @Sinaesthetic check the permissions on that "folder" key

Comment: code updated: added a way to delete all keys in one action so you can save API trips for each key deleted...